# Check if field collection image field exists - empty field creates error

Tags: symfony, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I have a field collection that takes three values (two text, one image). When I render these to the page like so:

```
{% for service in node.field_sub_service %}
        {% set subservice_id =  service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_title.value|lower|replace({" ": "-"}) %}
        <div id="{{subservice_id}}" class="subservice">
             <h5>{{service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_title.value}}</h5>
             <p>{{service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_description.value}}</p>

             <img src="{{file_url(service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.uri.value)}}" />
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Everything works fine unless the image field is blank. So I tried to set up a typical

```
    {% if service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.uri.value %}
        <img src="{{file_url(service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.uri.value)}}" />
{% endif %}
```

and

```
{% if service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.uri.value is defined %}
      <img src="{{file_url(service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.uri.value)}}" />
{% endif %}
```

Seems like no matter what unless the image field has a value I get the error following here

> Twig_Sandbox_SecurityError: Calling "uri" method on a
>   "Drupal\field_collection\Entity\FieldCollectionItem" object is not
>   allowed

*UPDATE*

I also tried the "| render" suggestion below in a couple fashions.

Comment: Seems like you should check the rendered field instead, not sure if it applies to this though: https://www.drupaleasy.com/quicktips/checking-existence-field-value-twig

Comment: I tried | render as per your article unfortunately it returns its own error or WSOD

Answer (score 0):

I ended up checking if the filename was NULL, however I do not find this to be an eloquent solution and I am still open for suggestions.

```
{% if service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.filename %}
    <img src="{{file_url(service.getFieldCollectionItem().field_sub_service_image.entity.uri.value)}}" />
{% endif %}
```